# where do i put the code for a new window

Tags: javascript, button

I cannot seem to remove the whitespace on the side of the footer as shown in the image. I tried width:100%; and almost every method online after i googled. here is the footer's html and css

```css
.container {
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      margin-right: auto;
         margin-left: auto;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .footer{
  background:url(../images/pw_maze_black_2X.png) left top repeat;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;

 }
 .footer-logo{
  margin:15px auto 35px;
  width: 76px;
 }
    .copyright{
  color:#cccccc;
  font-size:14px;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
 }
 .copyright a{
  color:#7cc576;
  font-weight:600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 }

 .copyright a:hover {
  color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer-logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/footer-logo.png" alt=""></a></div>
            <span class="copyright">Copyright © 2015 | <a href="http://bootstraptaste.com/">Bootstrap Themes</a> by BootstrapTaste</span>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

anything else i can try?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. "anything else i can try" for what? The title isn't even nearly related to the question.

Comment: Give us the link to the images @J.doe

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
    .container {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer{
    background:url(../images/pw_maze_black_2X.png) left top repeat;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;

}
.footer-logo{
    margin:0px auto;
    width: 76px;
}
.copyright{
    color:#cccccc;
    font-size:14px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
.copyright a{
    color:#7cc576;
    font-weight:600;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.copyright a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Where is the link to the picture?

Comment: You could do like <img src="website.com/image.jpg"> duh?

Comment: it's a html file on my computer. how does giving u a img tag gonna give you an image?